# Manual recursive delete throws "deleted instance passed to merge" in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-annotations, spring-transactions

NOTE: I am using a J2EE Spring MVC + Hibernate with both using annotations for this.

I have a file system modeled in hibernate with a hierarchy of folders and files in these folders.  The folders each refers to their parent folder or null if they are a root folder.  They do not have references to their children since there is a bit of polymorphism there and I decided it would be best to query to retrieve children.  Regardless, that combined with the fact that I have a requirement to use MySQL triggers to track history in the database, means that Cascading delete is not an option.

As a result I have to delete things manually.  Now, the recursive logic for this seems fairly straight forward, all I should have to do is the following in the folder DAO:

```
// Pseudo-java-code
deleteFolder(Folder folder)
{
  Set<Folder> folders = getFoldersInFolder(folder);
  for (Folder child:folders) {
    deleteFolder(child);
  }
  Set<File> files = fileDAO.getFilesInFolder(folder);
  for (File f:files) {
     fileDAO.deleteFile(f);
  }
  remove(folder); // method from org.execution.dao.JpaDao
}
```

Unfortunately I keep getting the "deleted instance passed to merge" exception when it attempts to commit the changes in the transaction.  The DAO is being called by a service which has the following transactional annotation placed at the top of the class:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have any other relationships to your files and folders except the relationships from their children? Do you perform other persistence operations in the same transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel kind of silly now that I know the answer.  I was calling "remove(folder);" after my call to the recursive function, meaning that the code attempted to remove the folder twice.